# How do you port forward to an internal ip address on your Windows 10 using Eset Internet Security antivirus firewall?

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, eset

I have eset firewall installed on my windows 10. I also have an internal server at port 10.1.1.2:3333 only accessible within the windows 10 system. I want to be able to create a firewall rule using ESET firewall rule that accepts incoming port of 5555 which reroutes it to 10.1.1.2:3333. I also want to create a rule that is a whitelist ip that can access this 5555 > 3333 redirect. How can I do this in ESET? I know it has something to do with Zones and Rules, but I wasn't sure which options should be set as the Rules portion have a "local" and "remote setting.

Comment: You don't;  You forward traffic to the client on the network device, through the router configuration, and allow the port on the server (client connected to the network).  Have you configured the port forward on the router?

Comment: @Ramhound Sounds more like the "Windows 10 system" is the "router" of concern (a VM host?).

Comment: @TomYan - Eset Internet Security is your average commercial off the shelf security product that either blocks or allows traffic on a port.  You are not going to forward all traffic on a port to another device on the intranet with it.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah, that's what I've guessed as well; my point was merely that the case can be valid (and it's doable on Linux).

Comment: @TomYan - I have never seen it done on Windows

Comment: @Ramhound well: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netnat/Add-NetNatStaticMapping?view=win10-ps

Comment: @TomYan: NetNat is for Hyper-V VMs.

Comment: @harrymc Not limited to, apparently. (It might be available only on system where Hyper-V is available though.) Besides, there's nothing indicating that the question isn't concerning a Hyper-V VM.